How to download a pdf file from chrome pdf preview using playwright
I have a page that I`m navigating on playwright and then i have to click on a element to open a popup to get a preview of the pdf file
    [popup] = await Promise.all([
      page.waitForEvent('popup', { timeout: 20000 }),
      frame.click('#imbImprimir'),
    ]);

I tried to get a buffer but I'm getting nothing using headless: true and
await popup.emulateMedia({ media: 'print' });
        popup.emulateMedia({ media: 'print' });
        const buffer = await popup.pdf({
          format: 'A4',
          printBackground: true,
        });

Is there any other way to download this page as a pdf?
if i open the page on headless: false i can see the file and download it as a pdf clicking on the arrow file preview
Is it possible to download this file using playwright?

Please share a [mcve] with your full code and the actual site.

I would use the waitForLoadState method in this to ensure the popup is fully loaded this can be done by adding
await popup.waitForLoadState('load') after you click the element to open it
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state
Additionally after PDF is generated and saved to a buffer you can save the buffer to a file with fs (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefilesync-method/) in a fashion like this
I hope this helps and happy testing!
fs.writeFileSync('output.pdf', buffer)


-> I faced the same problem earlier. I solved it by setting the attribute value of the download PDF button and then clicking on that button.
-> You can check the sample code for more details
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test.only('test', async ({ page }) => {

await page.route('**/*', route => {
   
    if (route.request().url().startsWith("https://googleads.")) {
        //console.log('Blocked ad request:', route.request().url());
        route.abort();
    } else {
        route.continue();   
    }
});

// Navigate to the page containing the PDF link
await page.goto('https://www.sampledocs.in/BrowseFile/DummyFiles/pdf');

// Selector for the element to which you want to add a new attribute
const elementSelector = "a[href*='SampleDocs-sample-pdf']";

await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    
    // Find the element using the provided selector
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (element) {
        // By adding this new "download" attribute we can directly 
        //download the pdf instead of opening in preview
        element.setAttribute('download','sample');
    } else {
        console.error('Element not found.');
    }
}, elementSelector);

await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

const downloadPromise = page.waitForEvent('download'); 
await page.locator(elementSelector).first().click();
const download = await downloadPromise;

await download.saveAs(download.suggestedFilename());

});

